# convert special characters in table ascii php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, utf-8, ascii

I want to make a search the database, where the user will type the word you want to search, a query is made, and if the word is found it shows the result.

Let's imagine that you want to search used the word "líder". In the database, I have the word "líder" saved as "l& iacute;der".

To search'm doing the following query:

```
$search = htmlentities($search_user);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM paginas WHERE content like '%$search%'");
```

the query says it found no results.

have also experimented with `htmlspecialchars` and my database is `utf8_general_ci` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem resolved:

```
$search = htmlentities($search_user, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Convert your search string to UTF8 before you search.

```
$search = utf8_encode($search);
```

Comment: I tried that before and it does not work. In my local server, the code works. but the web server does not

Comment: Are you using the same database both places? Are you sure the collation is the same on both databases if so? Find out where the configuration differs.

Comment: yes, I confirmed several times. that's why I created the post

Comment: The confugration differs in some way, otherwise the result would be the same.

Comment: yes, I am also of that opinion. I will confirm again. thank you!